# Spring cloud Gateway router always gives 404 error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a spring cloud project. This project consists of three main parts: A service discovery with `Eureka`, A gateway with `Spring Cloud Gateway` and service for REST API endpoints. I want to define API endpoints like this:

```
GET
/available
```

and route them with a path predicate in gateway:

```
GET
/service-one/available
```

To achieve this, I've added this route in gateway's yml file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:                
      routes:
      - id: service_one
        uri: lb://service_one
        predicates:
        - Path=/service-one/**
        filters:
        - StripPrefix=1
```

but when I try

```
// 9000 is the gateway's port number
http://localhost:9000/service-one/available
```

I get this error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "...",
    "path": "/service-one/available",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": null,
    "requestId": "..."
}
```

More details:

Spring Boot version: 2.4.5
Spring Cloud version: 2020.0.2

- **Discovery**:

`pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=8761
spring.application.name=discovery
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Application startup:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DiscoveryApplication {
    // ...
}
```

- **Gateway**:

`pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true 
          lower-case-service-id: true  
      httpclient:
        wiretap: true
      httpserver:
        wiretap: true                  
      routes:
        ##
        ##
      - id: service_one
        uri: lb://service_one
        predicates:
        - Path=/service-one/**
        filters:
        - StripPrefix=1         
        ##
        ##        
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
```

- **Service**:

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=service_one
server.port=8080
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

Service Endpoint:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@RestController
public class ServiceOneApplication {
    // ...
    @GetMapping("/available")
    public String available() {
        return "Hi, Service One is available";
    }
}
```

Comment: @spencergibb Hi, can you help me on this?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Currently I'm working on another project.